# port fowarding with login by .pem key

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm trying to simply forward a port from my local machine to VPS.
VPS is also ubuntu.

Getting the error in console, while trying to connect:

```
9350:~$ channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Thats how i setup a tunnel:

```
9350:~$ ssh -i *****key.pem -N -f -L 14265:34.***.81.28:14265 ubuntu@34.***.81.28
```

netstat:

```
9350:~$  netstat -nltu 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:14265         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

update:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 14265 for 34.***.**.28 port 14265, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 58566 to 127.0.0.1 port 14265, nchannels 3
```

seems like it forwarding to localhost?

What is wrong?

Comment: can you try with a different port.

Comment: yeah tried, the same thing.

Comment: Your process is listening only on `127.0.0.1:14265`, so that is the IP:port you need to forward in your `ssh` command: "`-L 14265:127.0.0.1:14265`"

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong - you did well. You forwarded port 14265 from localhost to the remote node (VPS) to 14265 port. But apparently nothing is listening there! This is why you receive *connection refused* which is expected.

If you want a proof run a client on remote (VPS) node at the port you are forwarding your `localhost` to. Netcat would do the trick (install first if missing):

First session at the remote VPS:

```
VPS # apt install netcat
VPS $ nc -l 14265
```

Second session at local (replace VPS accordingly and add other flags to ssh):

```
$ ssh -N -L 14265:VPS:14265 ubuntu@VPS
$ telnet localhost 14265
test test test
^D
$
```

At remote node `netcat` should echo your test strings.
See? It works. If you don't have `netcat` running, the `telnet` would reply with *connection refused*.

The bottom line? Forward the source port to something which listens actively at the target.